# Why plotly graph objects doing automatic binning?

Tags: python, dataframe, plotly

Can we avoid auto binning when I want individual entries even if there are large number of x values.
Even autobinx=false is not working.
I tried setting nbinsx

```
fig.add_trace(go.Histogram(x=data['col_x'], y=data['col_y'], histfunc='max', nbinsx=0, autobinx=False))

fig.add_trace(go.Histogram(x=data['col_x'], y=data['col_y'], histfunc='max', nbinsx=data.shape[0], autobinx=False))
```

Answer (score 0):

When you set *nbinsx* equals to 0, its value by default, you're asking for automatic binning.

If you put another value greater, the chart renders it

see https://plotly.com/python/reference/histogram/#histogram-nbinsx

Comment: I do not want any binning. I tried nbinsx = 0 as well as nbinsx=numberOfRows but still same binning happening

Comment: I didn't get why you want a histogram without any binning. if you pass nbinsx=1 you will get a bar chart.